# Understanding the output of cvFilter2d

Tags: python, opencv, filtering

I have convolved a filter with an image using cvFilter2D. I am using python 2.6 and OpenCV 2.0. The filter is a second spatial derivative similar to the Laplacian. (I would use the Laplacian if the output fit my needs, I want the directional derivatives reported separately). My question is about interpreting the output. In my experience (and if this is wrong, please correct me) cvFilter2d works with 8bit unsigned images, and returns an 8bit unsigned image. A derivative filter like I am using will return negative values.

For this algorithm, is the output shifted so that 128 is equal to zero? I know this is a simple question, but I have not been able to find an answer to this online.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "delta" parameter you can pass to the function to offset the result if you are writing to an unsigned output image type

```
void filter2D(const Mat& src, Mat& dst, int ddepth, const Mat& kernel, Point anchor=Point(-1, -1), double delta=0, int borderType=BORDER_DEFAULT)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I hadn't made the connection for the delta parameter.